# Access eclipse plugin from ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse TFS plugin.

I am running ant script within eclipse. The real problem is that several files are not marked as modified after build script finished its execution.

So is there any way(cmd, sys calls, etc) I can access eclipse plugin from ant?

**UPDATE 1**

Code sample

```
<target name="test" description="test call.">
        <replaceregexp file="${bc.file}" flags="sgi" match="${regexp.defaultdomain}" replace="${replace.defaultdomain}" />
        <eclipse.refreshLocal depth="infinite" resource="BC" />
</target>
```

Assume that BC is in my workspace.

This doesn't work

Comment: Is this on windows or another OS?

Comment: You just want to check the files out?  Why not either check them out with the TFS command-line client or with ant tasks for TFS?  The plug-in for Eclipse will see that they were checked out.

Comment: @James Reed, Yup. Win 8.

Comment: @EdwardThomso, yup will try that.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I modify file with ant, and I want files to be marked as modifed in eclipse.

Comment: And are you using the ant task for TFS to do this?  Or the command line client?  Unless you use a *local workspace* in TEE 2012 and TFS 2012, you must pend this change manually.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, for TFS I use eclipse plugin. I don't really know if we use local workspace or some another. THe approach is the same as with SVN, not like git or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse provide Ant tasks you can call from your build, as soon as you run it within Eclipse.
See http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fant_eclipse_tasks.htm

If this is about refreshing files which has been modified by your script, see `eclipse.refreshLocal`.

Comment: I am sorry, but eclipse.refreshLocal doesn't work. I'v tried it with infinite depth param.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov actually, if you're using local workspaces (in TEE 2012 against a TFS 2012 server) then reresh local should work - TFS plug-in for Eclipse will detect changes to the files and check them out for you.

Comment: The resource pointed by `eclipse.refreshLocal` should be a reference to a resource in Eclipse. So `BC` is the name of the project in Eclipse ? If it is a local folder, then it should better be `eclipseProjectName/BC`.

Comment: @NicolasLalevée refreshing the resources doesn't necessarily have any impact on whether they're checked out in TFS or not.

Comment: @NicolasLalevée, What do you mean by project and folder? WHen I open the project perspective the BC is the top folder. Moreover if i specify something wrong, the eclipse tells me about it. So no problems with BC.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you run the Ant script. I assume you choose "Run as Ant build" from one of the menus. If so, that actually created a launch configuration which you can modify. Therefore use Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations. Select your launch configuration, switch to the "Refresh" tab and check the option to refresh the workspace after a run of that script.

Comment: I run ant script from ant perspective.